# Como Calcular Juros em uma API Node JS?

Tags: node.js

Eu criei uma função que recebe um valor e acrescenta 10% em cima do valor.

A pergunta é:

- Eu quero que se o usuário digitar um valor igual ou menor que 100 ele acrescenta 10%. Agora se o valor for maior que 100 ele acrescenta 15%.

Veja o exemplo:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

const porcentagem =  parseFloat (10/100)

const calculaImpost = (valor) => {
  return parseFloat(valor * porcentagem)
}

app.post('/calcular', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    imposto: calculaImpost(req.body.valor)
  })
})

app.listen(3000, (req, res) => {
    console.log('Server is Running')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Qual a necessidade do parseFloat? 10/100 = 0.1, parseFloat(10/100) = 0.1

respondendo sua pergunta

```
const calculaImpost = (valor) => {
  if(valor === 100 || valor < 100) {
   return valor * (10/100);
  } else {
   return valor * (15/100);
  }
}
```

Comment: show!!! Muito obrigado!!!